# Dialogflow v2 REST call returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: dialogflow-es

I get a 400 Bad Request when issuing this entityTypes.create call:

```
wget --header="Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
 --post-data=' { "displayName": "writer1", "kind": "KIND_MAP", "autoExpansionMode": "AUTO_EXPANSION_MODE_DEFAULT", "entities": [ { "value": "Virginia Woolf", "synonyms": [ "Virginia Woolf" ] } }' \
 https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/MyProject/agent/entityTypes
```

but this -- entityTypes.list -- works OK:

```
wget --header="Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/MyProject/agent/entityTypes
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `--post-data` uses a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The API requires the content-type of `application/json`.

I tend to use something more like

```
wget \
 --header="Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
 --header="Content-type: application/json" \
 --post-data='{ ... }' \
 https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/MyProject/agent/entityTypes
```

Comment: Thx. Clearly required..  Also had a malformed json expression that needed to be fixed.